Users are creating duplicate cases from an account record by clicking the Create New Case button multiple times
I have a scenario where I have a button called Create New Case. Users can create a case from an account record, but the problem is that it creates duplicate cases from the account record. Why? Because users click the button multiple times, resulting in multiple transactions being initiated.
One approach I'm considering is to check whether the account status is "In Progress" as soon as the user clicks the button. If it isn't, the process should be stopped, and a FOR UPDATE should be used to lock the record. If the status is "In Progress," the case creation proceeds. If a DML_LOCK_ERROR is encountered, the process should also stop, as it indicates that different transactions are trying to operate on the same record.
However, I'm wondering what will happen if two or three transactions start at the same time. My understanding is that only one will succeed, while the other two will encounter a lock error due to the FOR UPDATE in the query. Is that correct, or would all three transactions be able to use FOR UPDATE if they start simultaneously?
What's your take on this approach, and do you have any other suggestions?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sales.managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5

Thanks for your time, but I would appreciate it if you could suggest some custom solutions.

Why do you need a custom solution?

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Why are multiple users creating a case on the same account at the same time?  It sounds like a problem with the business process.  Please [edit] your post to include a clear example where multiple users might create a case on the same account for the same exact reason.
